# Face Detection and tracking with Camera X and ML Kit - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, face-detection, android-camerax, google-mlkit

To implement face detection expressed in this blog with Camera X and ML Kit, with custom overlay.
That enables the shutter button only when the face is in the bounding box.

[Expected result video and Starter source code with CameraX included](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1QEM9rIYbEA3GYx1b5PacIFntJfTrSqHg)

https://medium.com/onfido-tech/face-detection-and-tracking-on-android-using-ml-kit-part-1-fbee4200d174

[image]

Following the Android camera X code labs, I could capture images and video.
Though ML Kit bounding box implementation requires a Graphic Overlay.

```
class OverlayPosition(var x: Float, var y: Float, var r: Float)

class OverlayView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context?,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val paint: Paint = Paint()
    private var holePaint: Paint = Paint()
    private var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
    private var layer: Canvas? = null
    private var border: Paint = Paint()

    //position of hole
    var holePosition: OverlayPosition = OverlayPosition(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
        set(value) {
            field = value
            //redraw
            this.invalidate()
        }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        if (bitmap == null) {
            configureBitmap()
        }


        //draw background
        layer?.drawRect(0.0f, 0.0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), paint)
        //draw hole
        layer?.drawCircle((width / 2).toFloat(), (height / 4).toFloat(), 400f, border)
        layer?.drawCircle((width / 2).toFloat(), (height / 4).toFloat(), 400f, holePaint)
        //draw bitmap
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap!!, 0.0f, 0.0f, paint);
    }

    private fun configureBitmap() {
        //create bitmap and layer
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        layer = Canvas(bitmap!!)
    }

    init {
        //configure background color
        val backgroundAlpha = 0.8
        paint.color = ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(context?.let {
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                it,
                R.color.overlay
            )
        }!!, (255 * backgroundAlpha).toInt())

        border.color = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")
        border.strokeWidth = 30F
        border.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        border.isAntiAlias = true
        border.isDither = true

        //configure hole color & mode
        holePaint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent)

        holePaint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The CameraX team provides a [GitHub code sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraX-MLKit) on how to detect objects with ML Kit and draw overlay on Preview. Please take a look and let me know if this works for you. The API is called [MLKitAnalyzer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/mlkit/vision/MlKitAnalyzer).

Comment: I'm unsure how to use MLKitAnalyzer to draw an overlay for a front-facing lens.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rddiuQOv6TaCyDAS1dzrmTceKd6OXX-r/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I've attached a started code with Camera X front-facing lens with image and video capture to test the implementation.

Comment: If you use CameraController, use the setCameraSelector API to switch back/front camera: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/CameraController#setCameraSelector(androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector)

Comment: Can you help me with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

In the layout file, we will define it as follows:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:scaleType="fillStart" />

        <com.example.facedetection.utils.OvalOverlayView
            android:id="@+id/oval_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>
// other codes
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the definition of the custom view Oval:

```
class OvalOverlayView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {
private val paint = Paint()
private val ovalRect = RectF()
private val blurPaint = Paint()
private val ovalPath = Path()

init {
    paint.apply {
        color = Color.RED
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 15f
    }
    blurPaint.apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        color = Color.BLACK
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        alpha = 128
    }

}

fun getOvalRect() = ovalRect
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)

    val centerX = width / 2
    val centerY = height / 2.8
    val radiusX = width / 2.8
    val radiusY = height / 3.4

    ovalRect.set(
        (centerX - radiusX).toFloat(),
        (centerY - radiusY).toFloat(),
        (centerX + radiusX).toFloat(),
        (centerY + radiusY).toFloat()
    )

    // The following code adjusts the outer part of the oval shape to be slightly blurred and the inner part to be transparent.
    ovalPath.addOval(ovalRect, Path.Direction.CCW)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        canvas?.clipOutPath(ovalPath)
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION") canvas?.clipPath(ovalPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE)
    }
    canvas?.drawPaint(blurPaint)
}
}
```

Next, you pass the received image to the image analyzer (here I'm using MediaPipe, but ML Kit would be similar :)) ). After obtaining the facial landmarks, you can select four facial landmarks (such as left/right cheeks, forehead, and chin). If these four landmarks are within the oval shape (you can check using [RectF.contains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF#contains(float,%20float,%20float,%20float))), it can be determined that the face is placed within the oval shape.

I have also developed a similar application, and you can refer to it in this [repository](https://github.com/tan264/Head-Pose-Estimation).

This is my first answer on the forum, and hopefully it won't be considered a low-quality answer.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).